# Mirror Image of a n-ary tree? Can anyone explain?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, mirror

This problem question asked at Amazon interview. I tried to find solution But I did not get the solution. Any one can solve the problem with the details.

Comment: What kind of tree? Binary, n-ary or something else? Well, no matter which, the duplicate should be an adequate starting point.

Comment: Right. I am looking for n-ary tree. I have updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: A binary tree is a special case of an n-ary tree. The code to mirror an n-ary tree is a pretty simple extension of mirroring a binary tree.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty simple, mirror image means left node of original node become right node for mirror image tree. You could use pre-order traversal and keep adding node as **left for original to right for mirror** and **right for original to left for mirror**.

```
public Node createTreeMirror(Node root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Node mirror = new Node(root.data);
    mirror.right = createTreeMirror(root.left);
    mirror.left = createTreeMirror(root.right);
    return mirror;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solution approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly standard interview question.

Think about the question this way, if you stood in front of a mirror with your tree what would it look like. I'd encourage you to actually draw a simple tree and stand in front of the mirror and draw what it looks like.

After you've done this, you may have realized that this question is almost identical to inverting a Tree. The process of inversion is, at every level, swapping the left and right nodes, and continuing to traverse if and only if the child node exists.

Here's some pseudocode to get you started:

```
invert_bst(bst):
    bst's left node = bst's right node
    if bst's left child is not null:
        invert_bst(bst left child)
    if bst's right child is not null:
        invert_bst(bst right child)
```

I would strongly encourage trying to implement this solution.

Good luck in your future interviews!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: No problem, it generally helps the community to mark an answer correct if it did end up working for you!